# Why don't I have a button to "Import Profile" at https://vscode.dev/editor/profile/github/{GUID}?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odhOl.png) - This Image has the IMPORT PROFILE  Option

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY5xu.png) - This Image Does Not have the IMPORT PROFILE  Option

I have Provided Two Images for reference about Actual and Expected Results. I want option of Import Profile.

So, I have a problem that it is showing Create profile instead of Import Profile (which is correct option) after exporting profile.

Answer (score 0):

You screenshots are of the vscode.dev special path for viewing Profiles exported as GitHub Gists. The docs for that feature can be found at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_save-as-a-github-gist.

Actually, those docs have an outdated string ("Import Profile in Visual Studio Code"), as demonstrated by your screenshot, the updated string for the button is "Create Profile in VS Code". The related source code for that string at the time of this writing is in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/279872bd965e4030c81129a9bf1ce1710ff7cd55/src/vs/workbench/services/userDataProfile/browser/userDataProfileImportExportService.ts#L723.

The code for the older string "Import Profile in VS Code" is in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blame/7a0fc6fe21f1661167b9795afa9784ebca9475dd/src/vs/workbench/services/userDataProfile/browser/userDataProfileImportExportService.ts#L344.

At an older point, it said "Import <profile name> profile in VS Code" https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/d132035d6b22c80cc78bf3ab50c24f05cb6fbdcc#diff-d74ea546351f9dc0df8f5df66119c69113933da150acc79c93f082cf6811d6c3L351

The code for the even older string "Import Profile" is in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blame/9c5f7ec9308881a8ebca1a88d6ea80518ef622cf/src/vs/workbench/services/userDataProfile/browser/userDataProfileImportExportService.ts#L204.

I'm not sure if these buttons do the same things, but for sure the difference is just due to VS Code updates over time.

Comment: So it means "Import Profile" and "Create Profile"  button is Basically the same in that context ?